# Akana API gateway is not working for secured SOAP services

Tags: api, soap

In Akana API Gateway, I am trying to setup a Proxy API for invoking SOAP service which is Secured(BASIC Authentication). When I tried to invoke the Proxy API from Test Client, it is not invoking the Target service.
It is showing the 503 service unavailable Error. However, It is working fine when I invoke the target service from SOAP UI.(I passed BASIC Authentication credential in SOAP UI)

I even tried, invoking the Proxy API from SOAP UI and passed the BASIC Authentication credential. Still I get the same error. ie., 503 service unavailable Error

Here is the error details

Cause: Binding component error encountered. HTTP Error [503:Service Unavailable] when accessing the URI [http://url]

Could any one please help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.
It was due to the incorrect Protocol. The WSDL URL is HTTPS. After importing the WSDL, the auto generated operation endpoint has HTTP. 
After modifying the endpoint URL manually from HTTP to HTTPs, it worked.